# How to compare counts from subselect?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to compare the count between two tables. Or more to say, output if the count from table1 is greater than from table2:

```
SELECT c1 > c2 FROM
(SELECT count(*) from table1) as c1,
(SELECT count(*) from table2) as c2
```

(real world selects are much more complex, but same structure)

Result: `Unknown column 'c1' in 'field list'`

How can I actually evaluate the counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the columns:

```
SELECT c1.cnt > c2.cnt
FROM (SELECT count(*) as cnt from table1) c1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT count(*) as cnt from table2) c2
```

Comment: Is there any advantage using `CROSS JOIN` over simply adding the `SELECT count(*)`s as a list like in my question?

Comment: @membersound, SQL standard compliant, i.e. expected to be portable.

Comment: @membersound . . . I abhor commas in the `from` clause.  Using them to actually mean a Cartesian Product is definitely an edge case.  But my recommendation is to always use explicit `JOIN` syntax so your intention is much, much, much clearer.